# Header files not found even though they are in the right directory?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, header-files

I'm fairly new to programming using linux so forgive me for any dumb errors I might make in my question but basically I am trying to compile using the terminal (C++) and my code in a .txt file however I keep getting a fatal error that my header file can't be found? When I try to type

`g++ -o test main.cpp header.h`

I get the error stating "header.h: no such file or directory" in the terminal. I've ensured that both the cpp and header files are in the same directory but no luck there. I've also used

```
#include <"header.h">
```

in my main.cpp and header file to try different fixes. I've researched and looked at different answers but no fixes either. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should not normally compile the header files. You also should try not to name your programs `test` as it could easily be confused with the standard [`test` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> #include <"header.h">
> ```

Use either

```
#include <header.h>
```

<sub>will lookup the standard include directories for these header files first</sub>

or

```
#include "header.h"
```

<sub>will lookup all include directory pathes specified with the preprocessor options</sub>

but don't mix these up.

---

Also you don't need to specify the header in the compiler command line

```
 g++ -o test main.cpp header.h
                    # ^^^^^^^^ omit this
```

That's what the `#include` statement in your code is for.

Comment: Use the later for your own headers, located in the same directory neighborhood as your code.